# Recursive algebraic data types via polymorphism in Haskell

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types, parametric-polymorphism

I am trying to understand the definition, de- and encoding of recursive algebraic data types given the functionality of universal polymorphism. As an example, I tried to implement the recursive type of binary trees via

```
data BTAlg x = Empty | Leaf x x
type BT = forall z. ((BTAlg z) -> z) -> z
```

the intuition being that the type of binary trees should be initial among all types `T` equipped with a constant `e: T` and a binary operation `m: T -> T -> T`, i.e. the "initial module" over the functor `BTAlg`. In other words, an element of `BT` is a way of assigning, for any such module `T`, an element of `T`.

The module structure on `BT` itself can be defined via

```
initial_module :: (BTAlg BT) -> BT
initial_module = \s -> case s of
  Empty -> (\f -> (f Empty))
  Leaf x y -> (\f -> (f (Leaf (x f) (y f))))
```

As a step towards pattern matching for `BT`, I now want to apply an element `x:BT` to the type `BT` itself, which I think of as some kind of encoding-decoding of `x`.

```
decode_encode :: BT -> BT
decode_encode x = x initial_module
```

However, this code results in a type error I cannot handle:

```
Couldn't match expected type `(BTAlg z -> z) -> z'
            with actual type `BT'
Expected type: BTAlg ((BTAlg z -> z) -> z) -> (BTAlg z -> z) -> z
  Actual type: BTAlg BT -> (BTAlg z0 -> z0) -> z0
In the first argument of `x', namely `initial_module'
In the expression: x initial_module
```

What's wrong here? I don't know why the type checker does not recognize that the universal type parameter `z` has to be specialized to `BT` in `x` in order for `x` to be applicable to `initial_module`; writing `(x :: ((BTAlg BT) -> BT) -> BT) initial_module` doesn't help either.

***Addendum concerning the motivation for defining `decode_encode`:*** I want to convince myself that `BT` is in fact 'isomorphic' to the standard realization

```
data BTStd = StdEmpty | StdLeaf BTStd BTStd
```

of binary trees; while I don't know how to make this precise inside Haskell, a starter would be to construct maps `BT -> BTStd` and `BTStd -> BT` going back and forth between the two realizations.

The definition of `toStandard: BT -> BTStd` is an application of the universal property of `BT` to the canonical `BTAlg` module structure on `BTStd`:

```
std_module :: (BTAlg BTStd) -> BTStd
std_module s = case s of 
  Empty -> StdEmpty
  Leaf x y -> StdLeaf x y

toStandard: BT -> BTStd
toStandard x = x std_module
```

For the decoding function `fromStandard: BTStd -> BT` I would like to do the following:

```
fromStandard :: BTStd -> BT
fromStandard s = case s of 
  StdEmpty -> initial_module Empty
  StdLeaf x y -> initial_module (Leaf (fromStandard x) (fromStandard y))
```

However, this gives the same typing problems as the direct definition of `decode_encode` above:

```
Couldn't match expected type `BT'
            with actual type `(BTAlg z0 -> z0) -> z0'
In the return type of a call of `fromStandard'
Probable cause: `fromStandard' is applied to too few arguments
In the first argument of `Leaf', namely `(fromStandard x)'
In the first argument of `initial_module', namely
  `(Leaf (fromStandard x) (fromStandard y))'
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think your transformation not preserve `z` type (look `Actual type: BTAlg BT -> (BTAlg z0 -> z0) -> z0`) but preservation is expected (look `Expected type: BTAlg ((BTAlg z -> z) -> z) -> (BTAlg z -> z) -> z`) I think your map is not fine defined (what do you wish to do?)

Comment: @josejuan: Thank you for your comment! I added some motivation for the definition of `decode_encode` to the question. Can you say what precisely is not fine defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the inferred type for `decode_encode`

```
:t decode_encode
> decode_encode :: ((BTAlg BT -> (BTAlg z -> z) -> z) -> t) -> t
```

it's clear that GHC has lost quite a bit of polymorphism. I'm not completely sure of the details here—this code requires `ImpredicativeTypes` to compile which is usually where my understanding starts to break down. However, there is a standard way for keeping polymorphism around: use a `newtype`

```
newtype BT = BT { runBT :: forall z. (BTAlg z -> z) -> z }
```

The `newtype` establishes an isomorphism `BT ~ forall z . (BTAlg z -> z) -> z` witnessed by `BT` and `runBT`. As long as we put those witnesses in the right spots we can go forward.

```
data    BTAlg x = Empty    | Leaf    x     x
data    BTStd   = StdEmpty | StdLeaf BTStd BTStd
newtype BT      = BT { runBT :: forall z. ((BTAlg z) -> z) -> z }

initial_module :: BTAlg BT -> BT
initial_module s = case s of
  Empty -> BT $ \f -> (f Empty)
  Leaf x y -> BT $ \f -> (f (Leaf (runBT x f) (runBT y f)))

std_module :: (BTAlg BTStd) -> BTStd
std_module s = case s of 
  Empty -> StdEmpty
  Leaf x y -> StdLeaf x y

toStandard :: BT -> BTStd
toStandard x = runBT x std_module

fromStandard :: BTStd -> BT
fromStandard s = case s of
  StdEmpty -> initial_module Empty
  StdLeaf x y -> initial_module (Leaf (fromStandard x) (fromStandard y))
```

In particular what's nice is that we use `runBT` to control when and how many times the type lambda in `BT` gets applied

```
decode_encode :: BT -> BT
decode_encode x = runBT x initial_module
```

One use of `runBT` corresponds to one unification of the quantified type.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you ever get stuck with this project then the code in [`recursion-schemes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes) implements all of this.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much both for pointing out the fix via `newtype` and for providing the reference to `recursion-schemes`!