# What are the values of a polymorphically encoded recursive algebraic data type?

Tags: haskell, recursion, polymorphism, semantics

The following question relates to [Recursive algebraic data types via polymorphism in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361736/recursive-algebraic-data-types-via-polymorphism-in-haskell).

Recursive algebraic data types can be realized in any language with the capabilities of System F using universal parametric polymorphism. For example, the type of natural numbers can be introduced (in Haskell) as

```
newtype Nat = Nat { runNat :: forall t. (t -> (t -> t) -> t) }
```

with the 'usual' natural number `n` being realized as

```
\ x0 f -> f(f(...(f x0)...))
```

with `n` iterations of `f` used.

Similarly, the type of Booleans can be introduced as

```
newtype Bool = Bool { runBool :: forall t. t -> t -> t }
```

with the expected values 'true' and 'false' being realized as

```
true = \ t f -> t
false = \ t f -> f
```

***Q: Are all terms of type `Bool` or `Nat` or any other potentially recursive algebraic data type (encoded in this way) of the above form, up to some reduction rules of operational semantics?***

***Example 1 (Natural numbers):** Is any term of type `forall t. t -> (t -> t) -> t` 'equivalent' in some sense to a term of the form `\ x0 f -> f (f ( ... (f x0) ... ))`?*

***Example 2 (Booleans):** Is any term of type `forall t. t -> t -> t` 'equivalent' in some sense to either `\ t f -> t` or `\ t f -> f`?*

**Addendum (internal version)**: In case the language under consideration is even capable of expressing propositional equality, this meta-mathematical question could be internalized as follows, and I would be very happy if someone would come up with a solution for it:

For any functor `m` we can define the universal module and some decoding-encoding function on it as follows:

```
type ModStr m t = m t -> t
UnivMod m = UnivMod { univProp :: forall t. (ModStr m t) -> t }

classifyingMap :: forall m. forall t. (ModStr m t) -> (UnivMod m -> t)
classifyingMap f = \ x -> (univProp x) f

univModStr :: (Functor m) => ModStr m (UnivMod m)
univModStr = \ f -> UnivMod $ \ g -> g (fmap (classifyingMap g) f)

dec_enc :: (Functor m) => UnivMod m -> UnivMod m
dec_enc x = (univProp x) univModStr
```

***Q:** In case the language is capable of expressing this: is the equality type `dec_enc = id` inhabited?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In System F (AKA λ2), all inhabitants of `∀α.α→α→α` are indeed λ-equal to `K` or `K*`.

First, if `M : ∀α.α→α→α` then it has normal form `N` (since System F is normalizing) and by subject reduction theorem (see [Barendregt: Lambda calculi with types](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/papers/barendregt.pdf)) also `N : ∀α.α→α→α`.

Let's examine how these normal forms can look like. (We'll be using Generation lemma for λ2, see the Barendregt's book for formal details.)

If `N` is a normal form, that `N` (or any its subexpression) must be in head normal form, that is an expression of the form `λx1 ... xn. y P1 ... Pk`, where `n` and/or `k` can be also 0.

For the case of `N`, there must be at least one λ, because initially we don't have any variable bound in the typing context that would take the place of `y`. So `N = λx.U` and `x:α |- U:α→α`.

Now again there must be at least one λ in the case of `U`, because if `U` were just `y P1 ... Pk` then `y` would have a function type (even for k=0 we'd need `y:α→α`), but we have just `x:α` in the context. So `N = λxy.V` and `x:α, y:α |- V:α`.

But `V` can't be `λ..`, because then it'd have function type `τ→σ`. So `V` must be just of the form `z P1 ... Pk`, but since we don't have any variable of function type in the context, `k` must be 0 and therefore `V` can be only `x` or `y`.

So there are only two terms in normal form of type `∀α.α→α→α`: `λxy.x` and `λxy.y` and all other terms of this type are β-equal to one of these.

---

Using similar reasoning we can prove that all inhabitants of `∀α.α→(α→α)→α` are β-equal to a Church numeral. (And I think that for type `∀α.(α→α)→α→α` the situation is slightly worse; we also need η-equality, as `λf.f` and `λfx.fx` correspond to `1`, but aren't β-equal, just βη-equal.)

Comment: Dear Peter - thank you for your answer, and sorry for the long time it took me to reply! Did you omit polymorphic abstraction and application from your terms? It seems to me that one has to consider normal forms with the leading abstractions possibly alternating between term and type abstraction, as well as application terms like `(y P1 ... Pk) [T]` inside these abstractions. However, this doesn't seem to induce any serious complications in your argument.

Comment: @Hanno My answer is given for the Curry-style version of System-F that doesn't have any type annotations or Λ in terms. But I believe the same argument can be used for Church-style as well. I'd also recommend [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/856347/37490) which gives completely different proof - it doesn't show that there are just 2 terms in normal form, but it shows that all terms of the boolean type are [extensionally equal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensional_equality) to `K` and `K*`.

Comment: Alright, thanks! However, I just stumbled across a sentence in the CoQ'Art book (p.XII in the Foreword) which confuses me: Concerning the polymorphic encoding of recursive types, it says "..., she [Christine Mohring] realized that the 'impredicative' encodings she was using did not respect the tradition where the terms of an inductive type are restricted to compositions of the type constructors. Encodings in the polymorphic lambda-calculus introduced parasitric terms and made it impossible to express the appropriate induction principles." Do you know how this fits with your answer?

Comment: I.e. (why) do things break down if we use the more expressive Calculus of Constructions?

Comment: @Hanno This is beyond my knowledge. If you find out, please add a comment.

Answer (score 4):

If we disregard bottoms and `unsafe` stuff, then the only thing you can do universally with functions `a -> a` is compose them. However, that doesn't quite stop us at finite `f (f ( ... (f x0) ... ))` expressions: we also have the infinite composition `infty x f = f $ infty x f`.

Similarly, the only non-recursive boolean values are indeed `\t _ -> t` and `\_ f -> f`, but you can also tie knots here, like

```
blarg t f = blarg (blarg t f) (blarg f t)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I should have been more precise in that I want the terms to live in System F, which then eliminates the possibility for recursion.